# What is Google Chrome Browser Version 0.A.B.C?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-analytics

I'm looking through my GA logs and I see a Google Chrome browser version 0.A.B.C. Could anybody tell me what this is exactly? Some kind of spider or bot or modified http header?

Answer (score 0):

The full user agent string probably looks something like this:

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13"

This is most likely a bot, but it could just be someone running an automated script using CasperJS or PhantomJS (or even a shell script using something like lynx) and spoofing the user agent.

The reason it looks like that instead of something that says  "My automated test runner v1.0" (or whatever is relevant to the author) is that this user agent string will pass most regular expression checks as "some version of Chrome" and not get filtered out properly by most bot checks that rely on a regular expression to match 'valid' user agent patterns.

In order to avoid it, your site bot checker would need to blacklist this string, or validate that all parts of the Chrome version to make sure they're all valid numbers. Even then, you can only do so much checking since the user agent string is so easy to spoof.